# Convert logstash 'mutable filter' configuration to fluentd filter config

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, macos-sierra, fluentd

I am trying to use fluentd instaed of logstash . I am currently having the following config for logstash and it is working. I want to read the 'message' field and wants to add some new fileds to create a chart in kibana.

**Logstash config**

```
filter {

        mutate{
            split => {      
            "message" => "|"

            }
            #sample: 2016-10-31 16:11:11,589|main|INFO|namespace:com.example|135.70.233.135|TDKDYIWGLMOJ|.....

            add_field => {"logEventTimestamp" => "%{[message][0]}"} 
            add_field => {"threadId" => "%{[message][1]}"} 
            add_field => {"logLevel" => "%{[message][2]}"} 
    }
```

I have tried in fluentd config as below. I am able to see the 'message' and other new fields in kibana but the new fields doesn't have any value in it. It seems, the split and assigning value to new fields doesn't work .

```
<source>
@type tail
path /log/**
#read_from_head true
tag test
format none
</source>

    <filter test.**>
      @type  mutate
      split{    
            "message" : "|"
            }

    replace {
     "logEventTimestamp" : "#{message[0]}", 
     "threadId" : "#{[message][1]}"
   }
</filter>
```